# echo every result with a font-awsome icon

Tags: php

Got this in a joomla article.
I want every result with a font-awsome icon.

I tried `echo '<i class="fa fa-star'.$key.'`  but don't now were to close class.

```
<?php 
$db = JFactory::getDBO(); 
$query = $db->getQuery(true); 
$query->select ('xx','xx','xx'); 
$query->from ('xx'); 
$db->setQuery ($query); 
$results = $db -> loadObjectList();
foreach($results as $value){
   foreach($value as $key => $data){
echo  $key.':'.$data." < br>";
   }
   echo"<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: Unclear about what's your problem, can you clarify?

Comment: why is your php code in a string?

Comment: found this part of code here. Trying to understand and learn from it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am late to this, but here is a formal and slightly compact form:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO(); 
$query = $db->getQuery(true); 
$query->select ('naamster','afbeeldingster','id'); 
$query->from ('lq8t3_sterren'); 
$db->setQuery ($query); 
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach($results as $value){
   foreach($value as $key => $data){  
        echo sprintf("<span class='fa fa-star'>%s:%s</span>", $key, $data);
   }
   echo  "<br />";
}
```

don't need to use extra variables..

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you

```
 echo '<i class="fa fa-star></i>'.$key;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what's working now!

```
    <?php
$prepend = "<span class='fa fa-star'>";
$append  = "</span>";
$db = JFactory::getDBO(); 
$query = $db->getQuery(true); 
$query->select ('naamster','afbeeldingster','id'); 
$query->from ('lq8t3_sterren'); 
$db->setQuery ($query); 
$results = $db -> loadObjectList();
foreach($results as $value){
   foreach($value as $key => $data){  
echo $prepend.$key.':'.$data.$append;
   }
   echo  "<br />";
}
?>
```

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ5Id.jpg)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bI6Cj.jpg)

Probably not the best way, but good for me :)
Next step is, someday to get every result in an open star-shape, ideas? :)